# Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string (help)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've been trying for the last six hours to figure out what is wrong with my code. My page keeps outputting 'Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string.' I don't know why! I looked at previous assignments, tried googling the type of error, and nothing has changed the output. I want to display my menu items by category id. Here's my code.

```
class Menu {
    public $conn;
    public function __construct() {
        $db = new Database();
        $this->conn = $db->conn;
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        $this-> conn = null;
    }

    /* Get function */
    public function __get($name) {
        return $this->$name;
    } // End get function

    public function __set($name, $value){
        $this->$name=$value;
    }

    public function menu_items($category_id = 0){
        try {
            $sql = "SELECT item_id, category, category_id, display_order, item_name, item_image, item_description, item_cost FROM menu_items WHERE category_id = $category_id";
          $result = $this->conn->query($sql);

            return $result;
        }
        catch (PDOException $e){
            echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE: Here is where everything is outputting. Could there be something wrong with this code instead?

```
include(ABSOLUTE_PATH . 'classes/menu.class.php');

// Create Menu object
$menu = new Menu();
$menu_categories = $menu->menu_categories();

include(ABSOLUTE_PATH . '_includes/header.inc.php');
?>

<hr />

<h2><?=$page?></h2>

<?
while($item = $menu_categories->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
// Retrieve menu items
$menu_items = $menu->menu_items($menu_categories);
$item_count = $menu_items->rowCount();

if($item_count > 0) {
    echo '<h3>' . $item->category . '</h3>';
?>

    <table id="menu_items" class="listing">
    <?
        // Loop through menu records
        while($item = $menu_items->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
            echo "\t<tr>\n";
            echo "\t\t" . '<td class="item"><h4>' . $item->item_name .     '</h4><p>' . $item->item_description . '</p></td>' . "\n";
            echo "\t\t" . '<td class="price">$' . $item->item_cost . '</td>'   . "\n";
            echo "\t\t" . '<td class="image"><img src="' . URL_ROOT . '_assets/images/menu/' . $item->item_image . '" alt="' . $item->item_name . '" /></td>' . "\n";
            echo "\t</tr>\n";
        }
    ?>
    </table>

<?
}}
?>

<hr />

<?
include(ABSOLUTE_PATH . '_includes/footer.inc.php');
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure the error is happening in this code? I don't see anywhere that you're trying to use a PDOStatement (the `$result` variable) as a string.

Comment: Well now you're changing your code around. What are you doing with the return value from `Menu::menu_items()`?

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this website I'm not used to the edits. I changed my code because I don't think I needed the extra records statement. It was just confusing me more. The return value is supposed to be used as a parameter for my menu's index page, I believe.

Comment: What does `menu_categories()` return? The error is that you are trying to treat an object (a PDOStatement object) as a string somewhere. Do you have a filename or line number to reference?

Comment: Ok, can you update your question to include the code where you're using `Menu::menu_items()`, and also the code for `Menu::menu_categories()`?

Comment: Check your web server's `error.log` file. It will tell you exactly which line of your code is failing.

Comment: The line it is saying is the problem is line 27 (which isn't the same number here). It's the line that reads **$sql = "SELECT featured, item_id, category, category_id, display_order, item_name, item_image, item_description, item_cost FROM menu_items WHERE category_id = $category_id";**

Comment: `$this->$name` that should should read as `$this->name` and we don't know what your PDO connection looks like, and if it's correctly syntaxed.

Answer (score 1):

Aha

here is your problem:

```
while($item = $menu_categories->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
// Retrieve menu items
$menu_items = $menu->menu_items($menu_categories); //<--Error
$item_count = $menu_items->rowCount();
```

You should call:

```
$menu_items = $menu->menu_items($item->id);
```

You are passing `$menu_categories` (a PDOStatement) into `menu_items()`, then trying to use it as a string directly in your query. That is where the error is actually occurring.

A good practice that would have made this error more apparent is to type check query parameters. So in `menu_items()`:

```
public function menu_items($category_id = 0){

 if(!is_numeric($category_id)) {
    //Do something better here, but just for example
    echo "Error";
    return false;
  }  
  try {
     $sql = "SELECT item_id, category, category_id, display_order, item_name, item_image, item_description, item_cost FROM menu_items WHERE category_id = $category_id";
     $result = $this->conn->query($sql);

     return $result;
   ...
```

Comment: Now when I run the code it reads "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string " and it refers to the same line as before. :(

Comment: So `$item` isn't what i thought it was. Its actually a stdclass object return from fetching.So you probably need to do `$item->id` to get the actual id. You can use `print_r($item)` to inspect it if `id` is not the actual attribute name.

Comment: You should also be using a prepared statement instead of a dynamic query. Among other things, it might have made this bug a bit easier to track down.

Comment: after identifying the item->id i got it to work! I'm so happy i'm crying. Thank you (everyone) for your help!